# Инициализация интерфейса Map

Tags: java, коллекции, java-hashmap

Что происходит в данной записи ?

```
Map<String, Object> m =  new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Интерфейс Map  через полиморфизм инициализируется  классом потомком   "HashMap" ? 
Для чего это делается ?

```
Map<String, Object> m; 
for (int i = 0; i < aProduct.length; i++) {

    m = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

    m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, aProduct[i]);
    m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PR, aPrice[i]);
    m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_QT, aQuantity[i]);
    data.add(m);
}
```

Comment: Что бы иметь объект HashMap, очевидно же. Вопрос уточните.

Comment: так почему сразу же не написать   HashMap<String, Object> m =  new HashMap<String, Object>();    ?     К  чему объявлять тип объекта как Map ?

Comment: Хороший подход в Java - програмирование на уровне интерфейсов, а не реализации

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смысл есть. А если в будущем вы захотите использовать не *HashMap*, а другую реализацию *Map*? Конечно, можно делать как вам вздумается. А сделано для того, чтобы можно было на лету менять конечную реализацию (к примеру, вместо *HashMap* использовать *LinkedHashMap*).

Поэтому и принято оперировать интерфейсами. Чтобы не связывать свой код жестко конкретными реализациями.

Comment: Еще надо помнить, что зачастую такая запись используется "by default", и если человека спросить зачем - он ответит что-то вроде "даже не знаю, я всегда так делаю"